# how to go to logout path in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rubygems, rails-routing

I am using rails 7 and When I click on logout it show an error that logout path is not found.
Here is my code of routes.rb, session controller and header section for logout:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  resources :articles
  get "/signup", to: "users#new"
  resources :users, except: [:new]
  get "/login", to: "sessions#new"
  post "/login", to: "sessions#create"
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

end




<li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete, class: "nav-link" %>
   </li>



 def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "Logged out"
    redirect_to root_path

  end
```

[image: error message(please note that i have already added ujs)]

Comment: @dbugger it still showing that error :(

Comment: @dbugger just a heads up - that link is pretty low quality. The change has nothing to do with Turbo streams. Rather its just that Turbo uses a "namespace" for all the data attributes it binds event handlers to to avoid potential conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

Your link is sending a GET request but it should be a DELETE. This is because Rails 7 comes with Turbo by default. Try:

```
<%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, data: {turbo_method: :delete} %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) instead of `link_to`. This creates an actual form element instead of relying on JavaScript.

```
<%= button_to "Log out", 
              logout_path, 
              method: :delete, 
              class: "nav-link" %>
```

For critical features like a log out that should "just work" this is recommended.

If you for some reason actually need a link that sends non-GET requests then Turbo attaches it's event handler to [`data-turbo-method`](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes) instead of `data-method` which was used by Rails UJS:

```
<%= link_to "Log out", 
             logout_path, 
             data: { turbo_method: :delete }, 
             class: "nav-link" %>
```

The only real reason you would want this today is if your want to add a link inside of a form element that performs a non-GET request. This is because nested forms are not allowed in HTML.

Note that in order for this to work Turbo has to be present on the page and working which can fail for many reasons depending on what asset pipeline you have in your application.